# How to fix repeating hierarchy month and quarter names issue in SSAS

Tags: ssas

I am developing a cube in SSAS using adventure works database. I have created a hierarchy as followed:- Year-->Month-->Quarter. I have set key columns for Month as Year and month and for quarter as Year and month and set the attribute relationships by rolling over quarter to month and month to year. When i deploy the cube after browsing it, i see the month names and quarters are repeated which is affecting mdx query to display quarters multiple times. Is there a way to fix this issue so that month names and quarters are not repeated in hierarchy. I searched a lot but couldn't find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your hierarchy.

You should change it from Year-->Month-->Quarter To Year-->Quarter-->Month which is the logical way of things. One year has many quarters and one quarter have many months and this is a hierarchy.